# Module not found when running vite preview for SvelteKit project

Tags: vite, sveltekit

Running npm run preview (vite preview) gives the following error message.

Full error message

```
error when starting preview server:
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module '/Users/username/code/my-projects/my-app/client/.svelte-kit/output/server/manifest.js' imported from /Users/username/code/my-projects/my-app/client/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/exports/vite/preview/index.js
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:393:5)
    at finalizeResolution (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:305:11)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:866:10)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1074:11)
    at nextResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:163:28)
    at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:838:30)
    at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:425:18)
    at ESMLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:522:22)
    at importModuleDynamically (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:110:35)
    at importModuleDynamicallyCallback (node:internal/process/esm_loader:35:14)
```

When checking `.svelte-kit/output/serve` I have both `manifest-full.js` and `vite-manifest.json`but not the missing `manifest.js.

`npm run dev` works fine btw.

the preview works if I change the name of `manifest-full.js` to `manifest.js` however, when I build (`npm run build`) anew, I never get the `manifest.js` file.

I also tried changing `my-app/client/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/exports/vite/preview/index.js`
The manifest is only mentioned in the following places in that file

```
const { manifest } = await import(pathToFileURL(join(dir, 'manifest.js')).href);
...
const server = new Server(manifest);
```

If i there change `'manifest.js'` to `'manifest-full.js'` it also works, even after building the project again.

I dont know if changing files in the `node_mudules` is a good fix, it feels wrong, since I thought you never are supposed to change those files.

Comment: What adapter are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help your issue, but I ran into this problem because I had a dynamic route defined with a route parameter like: [[slug]/+page.svelte](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahikm.png). However, I didn't have any code in the +page.svelte file yet to handle the dynamic route parameter. In my case I just deleted the [slug] folder and the +page.svelte file inside the folder. I was then able to build and run the preview command. (I'll add that I am doing SSG (static site generation) in my project as well, if that matters)

Comment: I'm confused, so you scrapped the whole thing that was causing the error?

Answer (score 0):

You're a lifesaver, music4computers. I had an issue with prerendering dynamic routes (using adapter-static). I searched for the `npm run preview` error to end up here but my issue was in the build process. Also, the build error showed up in white so was invisible to me.

```
 node:internal/event_target:1054
   process.nextTick(() => { throw err; });
                            ^
 Error: The following routes were marked as prerenderable, but were not prerendered because they were not found while crawling your app:
   - /dashboard/survey-menu/[id],  - /dashboard/view-survey/[id]
 
 See https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/page-options#prerender-troubleshooting for info on how to solve this
```

I fixed it with the following my page.js file (slug is your URL pram) as a hack until I have internal links to the dynamic route

```
export function entries() {
    return [
        { slug: '1' },
    ];
}
```

I found an explanation at: https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/discussions/8688
TLDR: The builder crawls your website for links such as /home/manifolds/123 to know how to prerender that dynamic route. It cannot prerender the route without knowing what the value of [slug] is or how many there are.